# Is it possible to install PowerShell Module for Sitecore and SPE Remoting module remotely?

Tags: powershell-extensions

Is it possible to install the PowerShell Module for Sitecore and SPE Remoting module remotely?
I'm wondering if it is possible to install it via ansible to a new Sitecore instance and then remotely install Sitecore update packages.
Maybe it is possible to install it via Web Deploy or SIF. Can't find any documentation related to it.